# SIA Prerequisite Install Error - Unable to parse [variable('WebDeploy.Version.Compare')]

Tags: sitecore-install-framework, sia

When setting up a new machine and using Sitecore Install Assistant (SIA) to install the Prerequisites for Sitecore 10.1.1 on Windows 10 64 bit, you may receive the following (abridged) error:

```
Unable to parse [variable('WebDeploy.Version.Compare')] - 
Exception calling "Evaluate" with "2" argument(s): 
"The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're installing Sitecore 10, 10.1, or 10.2, SIA requires Microsoft Web Deploy 3.6 to be installed on the machine as a prerequisite to the SIA prerequisite installation.  I assume that this is due to the fact that there's not a publicly available download link for this component.  I was able to get around this issue using the following steps:

1. Uninstall any newer versions of MS Web Deploy
2. Manually install Web Deploy 3.6 from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43717
3. Remove this item from the `Prerequisites.json` file:

   ```
       "InstallWebDeploy3.6": {
           "Type": "StartProcess",
           "Params": {
               "FilePath": "[variable('WebPlatformCmd')]",
               "ArgumentList": "/Install /AcceptEULA /SuppressReboot /Products:WDeploy36PS",
               "Wait": true
           },
           "Skip": "[variable('WebDeploy.Version.Compare')]"
       },
   ```